# IE8/IE9 Detect is third party cookies enabled if no then enable?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Is there any way to write any sniffer to detect the third party cookies on IE8/9 and if not enable then enable.

Code :

navigator.cookieEnabled gives the cookies enable but my requirement to get is this browser able to accept cookies from any domain.

Comment: The whole point of user-controlled browser settings is to prevent that sort of abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change browser settings with JavaScript running from within a page.

Comment: OK. I agree that changing browser setting through sniffer against the browser security. 

I want to know the way through which I can check.. Does this browser accept third party cookies or not.

Comment: Try to set a cookie from another domain. If it works, then you'll know ;)